# Neo4j Cypher: Match a node with two specific properties out of many

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of nodes of type "Noun", each of which has the same properties, and each node of type Noun has those properties with different values.

For example, say I've got a hundred Noun nodes with properties `a`, `b`, and `c`. I'm looking for a way to extract the nodes whose properties `a` AND `b` match specific values, i.e something like

```
MATCH (n:Noun) WHERE n.a='PropertyValue1' AND n.b='PropertyValue2' RETURN n
```

These nodes exist, but for some reason the above query won't return them. 
If I try instead

```
MATCH (n:Noun) WHERE n.a='PropertyValue1' RETURN n
```

I will get a bunch of nodes with `PropertyValue1` but I only need those that ALSO have `PropertyValue2` (which in this case is actually a single node). I don't care about what value property `c`has.

The first query above returns (`no changes, no records`).

EDIT: I matched the node with the above properties using its ID and the output is the following

```
{ 
  "countryAcronyms": "ES ",
  "dictionary": "LanguageName",
  "ir": "espanol",
  "gps": "null",
  "er": "Español"
}
```

What I am interested in are the `"countryAcronyms"` and `"dictionary"` properties: they need to be `"ES"` and `"LanguageName"` respectively. 
On inspection it seems that `"ES"` is actually `"ES "` but updating the query including the space won't return the node, again.

Comment: "These nodes exist, but for some reason the above query won't return them." It totally should. Are you sure there is no typo and you check for correct types (e.g. strings vs integers). Also, it's just a syntax sugar, but you might consider rewriting your queries using a shorter notation for properties: `MATCH (n:Noun {a: 'PropertyValue1', b: 'PropertyValue2'}) RETURN n`

Comment: Indeed, I tried using that query as well and it doesn't return the expected node. I will update my answer with additional information.

Comment: Please, make a [console](http://console.neo4j.org/) with some sample data and the query to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem there. 
I did `create (n:Noun{dictionary:"LanguageName", countryAcronyms:"ES ", gps:"null", er:"Español", ir:"espanol"}) return n`

And queried `match (n:Noun{dictionary:"LanguageName", countryAcronyms:"ES "}) return n`

Returns without problem.

Comment: In your original DB, do the separate queries `MATCH (n:Noun{dictionary:"LanguageName"}) RETURN ID(n);` and `MATCH (n:Noun{countryAcronyms:"ES "}) RETURN ID(n);` both return the same ID?

Comment: You may want to trim the `countryAcronyms` string to get rid of that white space, or possibly replace the value explicitly. There might be a chance you imported some special characters from whichever file you used for loading data that introduced this, and I'm not certain if a trim() is enough to get rid of it. Let us know how the testing goes.

Comment: @InverseFalcon

Indeed, I had to trim the countryAcronyms string to get rid of the whitespace. For some reason including the whitespace in the query didn't work. I fixed the file from which I imported the data to remove the whitespaces and got it working. Thank you for the help!